# .Net and Security

Tags: .net, security, acl

I'm looking over my security model and is wondering how you handle security (access control) in your projects?

I'm not interested in simple winapps or webapps, but in n-tier applications. How do you control access? Do you do it in each tier, or only in the User/Service frontends? Are you using a homebrewed solution or are there any standard ways? Are you using IPrincipal and IIdentity, in that case: How?

Lot's of questions. Answer those that apply to you. All answers are most welcome.

Comment: You cover a huge amount of gound with this one posting. Can i suggest you do some reading first, then come back with specific questions? What you have asked is enough to fill a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you do it in each tier, or only in
>   the User/Service frontends

Authentication (authN) and/or authorization (authZ) should be done "nearest" to the resources which means that you must do authN and authZ on each layer- this is inline with defense in depth strategy. Always assume the "caller" has been compromised so you need to verify and validate the identity of caller.

> Are you using a homebrewed solution or
>   are there any standard ways?

It is usually a good idea to follow standard ways, unless you are certain about robustness of your homegrown solution, same applies regarding encryption

> Are you using IPrincipal and
>   IIdentity, in that case: How?

If it is totally a Windows environment, yes, using IPrincipal and IIdentity makes sense. The "how" party is tricky - just look at [MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa302401), you can extend the IPrincipal and IIdentity  to implement your own authN and authZ in case of non-homogeneous (non-Windows) network.

Good luck!

Comment: What standard ways are there?

Comment: It depends on the type of resource you are trying to control access to. For example, if you want to authenticate end user to a web app, you can use Form Authentication. If you are authenticating an automated system (like web service client) you can use Client Certificate authentication.  For intranet scenario, you can use Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by learning Forms & Windows Authentication in ASP.net. Everything else follows.